# Keyboard hiding lower buttons on small Android screens

Tags: mobile, navigation, android, scrolling, keyboard

I have a application `(Android)` which have scroll `activity form`. On which there is a button for next screen (lowest of `scroll`). It's looking fine on large screens of android devices. But keyboard hides around **60% screen** of small `android` screen and even not `scroll` after a limit so not reachable to that next screen button.

Anyone have solution specially for android small screen then please tell me.

Answer (score 4):

If it's just a screen with text on it, then there are two options that **work on both a large and a small screen** equally well:

1. **Navigate by swiping**.   Swipe left or right should related to back and forward respectively.  This is a common pattern that has proven to work.
2. Place thin **transparent navigation bars** on the left and right with a clickable area much larger than the actual bar (minumum 48dp, Android's measurement unit), so that a tap on the right side of the page is interpreted as next, and a tap on the left side of the page is interpreted as back.

[image]

There is also nothing stopping you from using both options, but I would **test this with users** before deciding on which one (or both) to use.